# How can I embed a tracking GIF in an Excel document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to add `www.sometrack.com/blah.gif` to an Excel document. My goal is to embed a trackable element (e.g. a GIF). I want to send a person this document, and if they open it, the pixel opens transparently.

In Excel I'm using this option: *Insert a picture* → select all files → filename `http://sometrack.com/blah.gif`

For testing I open the Excel document on my computer, but I get no response on the tracking server (no change in timestamp or IP address). When I open the GIF directly, it works.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Do you want to embed a tracking pixel in an Excel file, is that it? Perhaps you can rewrite your question and clarify what precisely your goal is, and also describe what you mean by "I get nothing".

Comment: @slhck is it better?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that excel will embed the image and remove any links to that image if you insert the image like that.

However, if you use the following method, it should work:

Insert an object, from the list of objects, choose image. 
In the tab Create from file, paste your url in there, and check Link to file.

Now press OK and it should work.

Comment: but what about article which say excel 2007+ have by default restrict all calls to open external content? is that the case..

Comment: Not sure actually if this image is being classified as an external content. Also I have no idea what article you're referring to. I've used this method succesfully in 2010 to include a file and make any changes to the file automatically update. The file was on the local intranet, and it worked. I'd classify that as external content. But give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't it will work show up on server logs during inital get ; but when i close the doc and open it again; I don't see any new server log made? any suggestions.

Comment: It seems this has been protected then. The only alternate solution I can think of is to place the xls file itself on your server and use your stats to see who accesses the file. You can then hand out a link to the .xls file. Note that if someone downloads it once, you won't see any subsequent downloads. You could look into some form of online/viewer that will show the excel file to the user in their browser.

Comment: thanks :) do you any free service that does tracking out of box for docs?

Comment: no, but you could even make a simple php script that would do it for you, using the header('location: url to file'); and some writing stats to a file.

Comment: but requires me to post it online; that i dont want?

Comment: Yes, but if the server uses apache (most do), you can use a .htaccess page to make it only accessible for specific ip adresses or password protect it, so you can protect it to only those who can see it.

Comment: I was able to take this to the next level by creating a 1x1 tracking pixel and inserting into Excel as a linked graphic as suggested by LPChip and then using a redirect service (short URL) like bit.ly to track the number of file times the file was loaded. Further, I've been able to use the same pixel multiple times by simply creating additional short URLs to the same file and renaming the redirects based on what reports or files are in question. Works great in my work environment.